# change value listener in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, listener, jtextfield

In my code if the user enters value in ComboBox 2 it reflects in TextField, but
if the user selects from the dropdown in Combobox1 without changing the value
in ComboBox 2 the value remains the same in Textfield it does not changes.want am i doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class D extends JPanel {
    public D() {

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        add(buttonPanel);
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3, 5, 5));

        JTextField field11 = new JTextField(15);
        field11.setEditable(false);
        buttonPanel.add(field11);

        JTextField field12 = new JTextField(15);
        field12.setEditable(false);
        buttonPanel.add(field12);

        JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox1.addItem("1");
        comboBox1.addItem("2");
        comboBox1.addItem("3");

        JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox2.setEditable(true);

        comboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                JComboBox comboBox1 = (JComboBox) event.getSource();
                JComboBox comboBox2 = (JComboBox) event.getSource();

                Object selected = comboBox1.getSelectedItem();
                if (selected.toString().equals("1")) {
                    field11.setText("10");
                    String cb3a = ((String) comboBox2.getSelectedItem());
                    double cb3b = Double.valueOf(cb3a);
                    String cb3aa = field11.getText();
                    double cb3bb = Double.parseDouble(cb3aa);
                    double cb3c = (cb3b * cb3bb);
                    String cb3d = String.valueOf(cb3c);
                    field12.setText(cb3d);
                   }
                else if (selected.toString().equals("2")) {
                    field11.setText("20");
                    String cb33a = ((String) comboBox2.getSelectedItem());
                    double cb33b = Double.valueOf(cb33a);
                    String cb33aa = field11.getText();
                    double cb33bb = Double.parseDouble(cb33aa);
                    double cb33c = (cb33b * cb33bb);
                    String cb33d = String.valueOf(cb33c);
                    field12.setText(cb33d);
                    }
                else if (selected.toString().equals("3")) {
                    field11.setText("30");
                    String cb333a = ((String) comboBox2.getSelectedItem());
                    double cb333b = Double.valueOf(cb333a);
                    String cb333aa = field11.getText();
                    double cb333bb = Double.parseDouble(cb333aa);
                    double cb333c = (cb333b * cb333bb);
                    String cb333d = String.valueOf(cb333c);
                    field12.setText(cb333d);
                  }

            }
        });


        comboBox2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                JComboBox comboBox2 = ((JComboBox) event.getSource());
                Object selected = comboBox1.getSelectedItem();

                if (selected.toString().equals("1")) {
                    String cb3a = ((String) comboBox2.getSelectedItem());
                    double cb3b = Double.valueOf(cb3a);
                    String cb3aa = field11.getText();
                    double cb3bb = Double.parseDouble(cb3aa);
                    double cb3c = (cb3b * cb3bb);

                    String cb3d = String.valueOf(cb3c);

                    field12.setText(cb3d);
                } else if (selected.toString().equals("2")) {
                    String cb33a = ((String) comboBox2.getSelectedItem());
                    double cb33b = Double.valueOf(cb33a);
                    String cb33aa = field11.getText();
                    double cb33bb = Double.parseDouble(cb33aa);
                    double cb33c = (cb33b * cb33bb);
                    String cb33d = String.valueOf(cb33c);
                    field12.setText(cb33d);
                } else if (selected.toString().equals("3")) {
                    String cb333a = ((String) comboBox2.getSelectedItem());
                    double cb333b = Double.valueOf(cb333a);
                    String cb333aa = field11.getText();
                    double cb333bb = Double.parseDouble(cb333aa);
                    double cb333c = (cb333b * cb333bb);
                    String cb333d = String.valueOf(cb333c);
                    field12.setText(cb333d);
                }

            }
        });

        buttonPanel.add(comboBox1);
        buttonPanel.add(comboBox2);

        try {
            InputStream ips = new FileInputStream("test2.txt");
            InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(ips);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ipsr);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                comboBox1.setSelectedItem(line);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D app = new D();
        JFrame m = new JFrame("D");
        m.getContentPane().add(app);
        m.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        m.pack();
        m.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

test2.txt:
        1
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are only setting field11 in comboBox1's ActionListener, there is no reason for field12 to change. Only the respective ActionListener will get executed when a JComboBox is changed, not both.

Put your calculation in a separate method and then set both fields in the ActionListener, so both of them change.

Apart from that, you should add a type parameter to JComboBox, e.g. `JComboBox<Integer>`. That way, you will have to cast less. The GUI should be initialized on the EDT.

Comment: The code works fine when the user enters in comboBox2,the calculations are reflected in  field12,but when keeping the same value in comboBox2 the user changes the dropdown in comboBox1 then the value of field12 does not change.how can i accomplish it

Comment: @user I understood your problem and stated how to fix it in my answer... I'm not sure how to make it any clearer?!

Comment: I have tried setting field11 and field12 in combBox1's ActionListener,but that too does not seems to works.Can u please help me

Comment: @user With your new code, when I change comboBox1, both TextFields update... isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No,if you see my code then i want combobox2 value to be multiplied with textfield11 and then display it in textfield12.But in this case combobox1 is getting multiplied with textfield11 and displaying.

Comment: I am stuck with this problem can anyone please help me..Any help would be truly appreciated.Thank you

Comment: I have made a method and am calling the method in comboBox1 and comboBox2 actionlistener,but it shows me nullpointerexception error.

Comment: @user You currently have a part of the code repeated 6 (!) times. Your first step should be to remove that duplication.